# Why ray_cast is behaving like this?

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics

Why the result of ray_cast function is giving me that result?
The hit point should be `Vector(0.5, -1.0, 0.0)`, but it is returning `Vector(0.666..., -1.0, 0)`

I have tried a lot of combinations to try to understand what is wrong, but no clue of what happens, so I decide to ask it here.

[image: Results]
[image: Results2]

Comment: Yes, it is the default cube. I double check and the two vector (v1 and v2) are what is showed in the image.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50716/strange-object-ray-cast-behavior/50718  You are ray casting from v1l in a v2l direction, it's not from-to.

Comment: Thanks batFINGER... In fact the function cast_ray expects a initial vector and a direction, giving by (vector2 - vector1).normalized()... Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to batFINGER, I found the error. The ray_cast function should be supplied with a point (v1, in my example) and the normalized direction, reached by (v2 - v1).normalized(). Now it is working as expected.

[image: Solution]